# Does Android have any way to nest or chain IntentServices?

Tags: android, networking, android-intent, intentservice

After starting my application, I need to do a few separate calls for data.  After all of these calls return, my application is ready to go.  Is there a good way to nest or chain multiple requests?  I want them to be cleanly separate from each other and was planning to use IntentServices for each.  I don't know a way of grouping them and waiting for their results other than just calling each individually from my fragment and waiting for all of their responses.  Thanks!

Comment: just call startService multiple times,  IntentService uses one background Thread so your intents will be queued and passed to onHandleIntent on by one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could try is, create a `BroadcastReceiver` for each successive `IntentService`. When one `IntentService` completes its work, you could send a broadcast for the next one, and start the next `IntentService` from the `onReceive()` of the `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: That's a much better solution than what I thought I may have to do.  My only complaint is it then spreads out the functionality...  Instead of looking at one class to see what data is loaded initially, I'll have to look at the activity and each BroadcastReceiver.  I'll accept this answer if there aren't any better solutions- I was hoping it would still be a bit cleaner.

Comment: When you asked about chaining Services, I remembered that its possible to do something similar using Broadcast Receivers. In fact, the framework seems to have direct support for a related concept (ordered broadcasts). Its even possible to make successive network calls using AsyncTasks, starting the next AsyncTask in the onPostExecute() of the previous one.